# How to prevent code from auto-restarting on code changes while debugging in PyCharm?

Tags: django, debugging, pycharm

While debugging a Django project in PyCharm, if I add a break point and then edit a line of code, let's say something simple like `x = 2`, the debugger will automatically terminate and restart.

Is there a way to prevent this? Obviously a restart is needed to rerun code, but it would be nice to walk through break points and add code as I go without starting from the beginning.

Comment: Related [Any way to prevent auto restart on changes when in debug?](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4414647376530-Any-way-to-prevent-auto-restart-on-changes-when-in-debug)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was adding --noreload as a parameter, so something like:

`runsslserver 8001 --noreload`